# imgur extract codes from links in C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, imgur

I'm trying to convert a imgur link to an embedded code.

I've found this Regex that works to extract the imgur code in JavaScript. I need your help in a code that extracts one or more matching imgur links from a string in c#.

Here is the JavaScript equivalent:

https://regex101.com/r/qI4lY7/3

The regex return matches the entire string starting from the http. So if I have the following string.

```
string a = "bla b la alb http://imgur.com/a/BmFoY#5i4b8Zz dsfs df";
```

The regex used:

```
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"(https?:\/\/imgur\.com\/a\/(.*?)(?:[#\/].*|$))");
```

The match.value for the following code:

```
 Match match = regex.Match(a);
```

Returns:

```
http://imgur.com/a/BmFoY#5i4b8Zz dsfs df
```

Which is not what I want to achieve. I need the matching code from the link, which is `BmFoY` in case of the example above.

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with your c# code. Please add code and problem description

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy added more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly did you want it to achieve? what was your regex in c#

Comment: @IdanShechter and how regex look like?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy sorry, I need to learn how to ask questions, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to grab everything from `http://imgur.com` to first space

```
var regex = new Regex(@"https?://imgur\.com/a/([^\s]+)");
```

Group will contain

```
"BmFoY#5i4b8Zz"
```

Comment: And how I extract the code from that link the 'BmFoY' one? Thanks,

Comment: @IdanShechter if you need part after `/a/` then you can catch it in a group. I hope with this hint you will finish your task